# The string was not recognized as DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

```
string date = "21/07/2022"; //Query from SQL
DateTime add_date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From one computer on the same field it is OK, from another computer on the same field it throws:

> The string was not recognized as DateTime

There is a parse that also accepts the code of the culture and according to this knows the pattern of the date?

Comment: Well as a first step, what *is* `date` on those two computers?

Comment: Apparently it isn't.

Comment: I don't think that `CultureInvariant` recognises `dd/MM/yyyy` as a date string - I believe that it uses `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: You should really use a non-string type to store the date in your SQL database e.g. `datetime2`, are you able to change it?

Comment: The code seems fine and can run on dotnetfiddle too. You should check upon the computer that bugged, like what value did it exactly retrieve, maybe more logging for you to debug. Currently the info you've provided is not enough.

Comment: @ChrisBD That is why `ParseExact` exists in the first place. So that there is no guessing.

Comment: @user16242098 `What you mean??` - I mean that on the other computer, it doesn't contain `21/07/2022`.

Comment: @GSerg
**I mean that on the other computer, it doesn't contain 21/07/2022** No way

Comment: What about `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);`?

Comment: @Xiang Wei Huang Is that okay? Will it work generically?

Answer (score 0):

Since I still can't comment...

Check your regional settings on both PC's. Also, make sure your table column is `date`. If it is of type date you could do something like this

```cs
// sql logic here

DateTime date = reader["YourColumn"] as DateTime;
```

If you really need it to be a (n)varchar in your database for some reason, it may be easier to convert it when querying the data using `Convert()`

Example
`select Convert(datetime, '12.06.2000', 104)` It will return a datetime from the input string.

Check this list out for other formats

[SQL Convert Date functions and formats](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-convert-date-functions-and-formats/)